# replacing version range with sed

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to replace version range
1.6,1.7 with 1.7,1.8 as below.

```
sed -i 's/version\>[1.6,1.7)/version\>[1.7,1.8)/g'
```

I have tried escaping [,),. etc. but it is not still matching [1.6,1.7)

What am I missing?

This is the full command I run to replace versions:

```
find . -iname 'pom.xml' -print -exec sed -i 's/version\>\[1.6,1.7)/version\>[1.7,1.8)/g' {} \;
```

GNU sed version 4.1.5

Linux **** 2.6.18-238 #1 SMP Fri Oct 28 08:42:39 PDT 2011 x86_64

**UPDATE:**

```
sed -i 's/version\>.*1.6,1.7)/version\>[1.7,1.8)/g'
```

worked for me. But that is still too generic.

Comment: please edit your post to include output of `sed --version` and `uname` . Good luck.

Comment: What do you mean by it's too generic? Please post an example of the line that you want `sed` to edit, and perhaps lines you do not want `sed` to change.

Comment: @Thor - I avoided the issue by using .*

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand. What string are you trying to match? If it is `version>[1.6,1.7)`, this substitution should work:

```
s/version>\[1\.6,1\.7)/version>[1.7,1.8)/g
```

There is no need to escape the `>`, but you should escape `[` and dots because they have a special meaning.

Comment: That's not correct - I know for a fact you need to escape >. The problem is in [ character.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to mention I run this in shell. > is the redirection operator, so I have to escape.

Comment: @Fakrudeen: No. The single quotes around the expression prevent the shell from interpreting `>`.

Comment: yes - you are right - But that is not the problem. It still matches version> correctly. See my edit in the post about working one. It is something to do with [

Comment: Escaping it with a backslash, as in '\\[' should work. You could also try '[[]' which should work too.